# how to stop Excel VBA from interpreting a dash (-) as a minus sign in a variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a response from an API that is returned in a hreq object. It looks like this

```
date: Wed, 22 Dec 2021 10:59:07 GMT
cache-control: no-cache,no-store,max-age=0
notification-box-id: xxxx-xxx-xxx
notification-message-id: mmmmmm-jjjjjj-xxxxxxxx
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 92
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000;
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-cache: Miss from cloudfront
via: 1.1 e6578585858556e63d91f7.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-pop: CDG50-P2
x-amz-cf-id: CqT8YCc6c3ydy4b5l6m4444cIdQr29Ns1A==
```

My code is then

```
    With hreq
        DoEvents
        .Open "POST", strUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/vnd.hmrc.1.0+json"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & USERRESTRICTEDACCESSTOKEN
        .send (body)
    End With
    
    headers = hreq.getAllResponseHeaders()
    text = hreq.responseText
    text2 = hreq.notification - Message - ID
```

Whenever I type
`text2 = hreq.notification-Message-ID`
Excel VBA editor changes it to
`text2 = hreq.notification - Message - ID`
and I end up with an error and code that will not run.

I cannot find a setting that allows a dash in a variable name.  Is it hidden somewhere or is there another way to retrieve this header information?

Comment: What VBA reference are you using?

Comment: Set hreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

Comment: Don't you start with `Dim hreq as ...`?

Comment: If you use `CreateObject`, you are using late binding, so the `as` could be `Variant` or `Object` - important to know is that it is a `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`-object. Would be good if OP shows more of the code

Comment: `text2 = hreq.getResponseHeader("notification-message-id")`

Comment: CDP1802 - Thank you